# Execute agrep within script | grep terminal output

Tags: linux, shell

Can I execute a grep in my script below?

```
echo 5
echo 4
result='çat output.txt | grep flag'
echo $result
```

The scipt gets used like
./script | ./program > output.txt

The script is used as input for the program, and the output of the program gets put into output, which I want to be able to grep for instantly. At the moment, it seems to finish without doing the grep command

Comment: `ç` should be `c`

Comment: This doesn't make sense. You can't grep the output before you write to the output.

Comment: @Barmar is there a way to read terminal output then? The program is set up so that only numbers are allowed as input, so the 4 is actually just exiting the program. This is why I have tried to put the contents in output.txt

Comment: If you're trying to feed those as input to another command, you should pipe them: `{ echo 5; echo 4; } | ./program`

Comment: But if you're trying to send input to a program and also process its output, the tool to use for that is `expect`.

Comment: @Barmar adding {echo 5; echo 4} throws an error- I dont think it is passing any of those as inputs to the program

Comment: You forgot the `;` after `echo 4`

Answer (score 0):

I have the impression you are using single quotes while it should be backtics. Luckily there is something easier to use

```
result=$(cat output.txt | grep "flag")
```

The `$(some_command)` is used for getting the results of `some_command`.

Comment: This is in the duplicate question. Although it seems he has other problems, since he wants to grep from the same file that he's writing.